# Listener for incoming emails

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

How can I implement a listener for incoming emails on Mango? Is it possible?

SMS is not possible, right?

Answer (score 2):

There is no API access to SMS or emails.

This was a deliberate decision as part of the platform design to prevent any data security issues about users data being accessed without their permission/knowledge.